# prevent video hotlink from external site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, jwplayer

I am using JWplayer on my website to play .mp4 files, when i check my site code the JWplayer code is like this.

```
<div class='jwplayer' id='jwplayer-0'></div><script type='text/rocketscript'>if(typeof(jQuery)=="function"){(function($){$.fn.fitVids=function(){}})(jQuery)};jwplayer('jwplayer-0').setup({"aspectratio":"8:5","width":"100%","primary":"html5","file":"http://mysite.se/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/sack.mp4"});
</script>
```

Now, how can i prevent someone from hotlinking that .mp4 files on a forum or another side or embed it on another player somewhere else if it's possible? i want the file only to be accessed by my own site if possible? i dont care if they download the file aslong as they dont hotlink it from my server.

Answer (score -1):

You'd probably have to rely on checking the HTTP Referer field of the incoming request. The referer, however, can be easily forged to get around this limitation, but as it is, this is probably the easiest solution.

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?example\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule \.mp4$ - [L,F,NC]
```

Where "example.com" is your domain.

Comment: You can also try using a restrictive crossdomain.xml file.

Comment: Hello

If i use that code you posted i cant embed any videos on my own site anymore, and then i just changed "example" and ".com" to my own domain.

Comment: Yes, if you use server-side hotlink protection, the player won't work. Been there, done that. Not a usable solution.